# How to set custom reports in a jasper report image in java netbeanas

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'm working on a shop management software, 
I got the db and everything set up, but when I want to generate pics for the reports. simple pics, just company logo.

But I want the pic to be stored on DB.

this is how you can manually set a pic. But how can I get it from the db?

[pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JhsDL.png)

The reason why I want it from DB is because the user will use the same software in different shops, and I dont want him to generate a new jasper report file just to change the logo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save it on db as blob and retrieve the image from db as imgStream